# How to add icons for Category for WordPress Single Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a WordPress theme and I want to add different icons for Category. Basically I want if I select Music category while adding a WordPress Post then there should be Music icon before category in single post.
( Screenshot added)

If I select Image category then there should be Image icon before category in Single Post Page. I am using WordPress and I actually saw this work on this WordPress theme:

[image]

[image]

I am planning to use Font-Awesome icons... Anyone here for help :)

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to make a field for the category for the icon and pull that into your data output.

Comment: You could also add an if statement in your theme code like: if ( in_category( 'image' )) { //icon-code } - check out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

Comment: I have embedded your images for you...

Comment: how it possible Brian?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a filter on the_category hook to modify the HTML of your `the_category` function and add a class name.  This code was obtained from a [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/add-classname-to-the-category-function) answer.

```
function add_class_callback( $result ) {

  $class = strtolower( $result[2] );
  $class = str_replace( ' ', '-', $class );

  $replacement = sprintf( ' class=""><i class="fa %s"></i>%s</a>', $class, $result[2] );
  return preg_replace( '#>([^<]+)</a>#Uis', $replacement, $result[0] );

}

function add_category_slug( $html ) {

  $search  = '#<a[^>]+(\>([^<]+)\</a>)#Uuis';
  $html = preg_replace_callback( $search, 'add_class_callback', $html );

  return $html;
}

add_filter( 'the_category', 'add_category_slug', 99, 1 );
```

The above function should add the required markup. Then, include the following CSS in you stylesheet.

```
.post-categories .music:before {
    content: "\f001";
}
```